# Ending an Event Driven Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript with HTML5.  When the user clicks on a button, an event-driven JavaScript function starts up.  When the user clicks on the button again, another instance of this function starts up. So I have two instances of the same function handling a event.  However I only want the new instance to be running.  How do I end the first instance of the?

An example is a function with the following code

```
Canvas.paper = Raphael(xOffset,yOffset,imageWidth,imageHeight);
masterBackground = Canvas.paper.rect(0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight);

window.onkeydown=function(e){
    // Event handler code
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    // Event handler code
}

masterBackground.mousemove(function(e){
    // Event handler code
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have some code to show as an example? For instance, what are these functions doing? Are they using setInterval, making ajax call, etc...?

Comment: Use a flag that indicates it's already running so as to prevent others from starting.

Comment: Provide some code please?

Comment: what do you mean "end the first instance"?

Comment: I have added some code.

Comment: By the first instance, I mean the first time the function starts up, it is running and handling events.  When I click the button again, I have two sets of event handlers.  I want to stop the end handlers associated with the first click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems apparent that something asynchronous and long-running is happening.

To prevent concurrent instances from running, just use a flag that is set when one starts so that others can't begin. Then when the current one finishes, reset the flag so that another can start.

```
 // Immediately invoked function, makes a variable and returns the handler
 //    that uses the variable as a flag.
button.onclick = (function() {

    // local variable, only accessible to the returned handler
    var running = false;

    // This is your event handler.
    return function(e) {
        if (running === false) {
            running = true;

            // run your asynchronous operation

            // after it's complete,  set `running = false;`
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Sorry about the slow reply.  I ended up with something along the lines of what you describe.  I initialized running to false as a global and then had code like "if (running){/* whatever*/}else{running=true;/* whatever*/}".  So subsequent calls to the function went to the "running==true" block.  Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to this, some of them library dependent, but "nicer" to look at:

For example, using jQuery:

```
<button>Click me</button>

<script>
  $('button').on('click', handleButtonClick);

  function handleButtonClick() {
    $(this).off('click', handleButtonClick); //disable click event
    //do various things you don't want duplicated
    $(this).on('click', handleButtonClick); //reattach handler
  }
</script>
```

OR:

```
<button>Click me</button>

<script>
  $('button').once('click', handleButtonClick); //attach one-time handler

  function handleButtonClick() {
    //do various things you don't want duplicated
    $(this).once('click', handleButtonClick); //attach one-time handler
  }
</script>
```

Most libraries support similar methods, if you'd rather do it vanilla JS, that is definitely possible of course as well. "am not i am" provided a nice example for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15976888/622129

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttonView = document.getElementById('buttonView');

buttonView.handleEvent = function(event) {
    window.alert(this.id);
    //this.onclick = null;
};

buttonView.onclick = buttonView.handleEvent;
```

Try it out: **http://jsfiddle.net/KHQ4y/**

*Edit: I posted this before you supplied your specific code, but you get the idea.*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure a function only runs once:

[example based on benny's example](http://jsfiddle.net/KHQ4y/1/)

```
function onlyOnce(proc){
    return function () {
        var result = proc.apply(this,arguments);
        proc = function () {};
        return result;
    }
}
```